# why i got error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8002000B) HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)?

Tags: c#

I have made a C# program and I SELECT the data to DATAGRIDVIEW ,

then I created a button to save the data in DATAGRIDVIEW as EXCELL file .

In some computers when I installed the program I can save the file as EXCELL but some computers I cannot save and export data to excell when click the button I got this error :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8002000B): Invalid index. (exception HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
   on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.get__Default(Object Index)
   on mamlaka_lab.PL.FRM_ORDERS_LIST.btnWord_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   on System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   on System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   on System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   on System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   on System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   on  System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   on System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   on System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This is the code used :

```
private void btnWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook work = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            worksheet = work.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = work.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Sheet1";

            

            for (int i = 1; i < OrdersDataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = OrdersDataGridView.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < OrdersDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < OrdersDataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = OrdersDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            var SavefileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
            SavefileDialoge.FileName = "نموذج استلام وتسليم ";
            SavefileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
            if (SavefileDialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                work.SaveAs(SavefileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }

            app.Quit();

        }
```

How to solve this error please I need your help ?

Comment: You sure that Sheet1 exists? `on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.get__Default(Object Index)` part from stack trace means no sheet was found by provided index (`work.Sheets["Sheet1"];`)

Comment: @Auditive I dont know how to be sure , its working in some computers and some computers not working , how to check ?

Comment: Simply - open and check .xlsx file is there Sheet1)) I think your trouble is because you looking for Sheet1 `worksheet = work.Sheets["Sheet1"];` then taking just `worksheet = work.ActiveSheet;`. It a bit confusing and probably `worksheet = work.Sheets["Sheet1"];` isn't needed at all and you need just current opened Sheet to work with it.

Comment: @Auditive that is the trick its working now after remove the line     worksheet = work.Sheets["Sheet1"];       thank you so much add the answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your file doesn't contains Sheet1, which you provide as index at:

```
worksheet = work.Sheets["Sheet1"];
```

Also you got `worksheet = work.ActiveSheet;` right after previous sheet retrieve and seems you really need only current (active) sheet, so `worksheet = work.Sheets["Sheet1"];` should be removed as unnecessary:

```
var worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)null;
// worksheet = work.Sheets["Sheet1"]; <-- not needed
worksheet = work.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "Sheet1";

for (int i = 1; i < OrdersDataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```